# Adding an auto-refresh rate to a Startup Application

Tags: startup-applications

I work for the IT Dept of an airport and we use 14.04 for our live view of tracking flights. I have the Flight Tracker scheduled to start 10 seconds after boot, but I would like to add an auto-refresh rate of 5 minutes to the program to keep track of flights and in case there is a moment where connection to the internet is temporarily down. How would I do this?

I have researched and found how to Delay the Startup Application but can't find a script for an auto-refresh

Do the program has autorefresh features? That's an application feature, noting to do with Ubuntu. –  Braiam 3 hours ago

No it does not. Before it was connected to Windows XP and had to have an HTML file targeting the application to give it an auto-refresh. I'm new when it comes to adding bash scripts for HTML to Ubuntu. But here is the HTML file that was XP:           –  scros6y 3 hours ago

My question is in bash would this be the same? Or would there be a different way to set this up? –  scros6y 3 hours ago

looks like a on-line application, is this "app" run in a web browser? –  Mateo 3 hours ago

Yes its an app that we run inside a browser. Basically its a live view of flights incoming and outgoing. Previously, through IE but now through Chrome –  scros6y 3 hours ago
1
This is independent of your operating system, you can use the exact same approach. Nothing to do with bash. –  terdon 3 hours ago 
1
but you could write a small script to auto open that web page every so often right? maybe chrome in kiosk mode... –  Mateo 3 hours ago

Would I need to place the HTML as a Startup or just place it in my home directory? –  scros6y 3 hours ago

I have it set now to open in Chrome in Kiosk mode –  scros6y 3 hours ago

I replaced the Web App File with the HTML File and this seems to have done the trick! Thank you! –  scros6y 21 mins ago

Comment: Do the program has autorefresh features? That's an application feature, noting to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: No it does not. Before it was connected to Windows XP and had to have an HTML file targeting the application to give it an auto-refresh. I'm new when it comes to adding bash scripts for HTML to Ubuntu. But here is the HTML file that was XP:                                                      <html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" Content="600;URL=flightview.html">
</head>
<frameset rows="*,0">
     <frame name="1" src="http://tracker.flightview.com/customersetup/littlerock/airtrafficlive/1024x768/">
     <frame name="2" src="">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: My question is in bash would this be the same? Or would there be a different way to set this up?

Comment: looks like a on-line application, is this "app" run in a web browser?

Comment: Yes its an app that we run inside a browser. Basically its a live view of flights incoming and outgoing. Previously, through IE but now through Chrome

Comment: This is independent of your operating system, you can use the exact same approach. Nothing to do with bash.

Comment: but you could write a small script to auto open that web page every so often right? maybe chrome in kiosk mode...

Comment: Would I need to place the HTML as a Startup or just place it in my home directory?

Comment: I have it set now to open in Chrome in Kiosk mode

Comment: I replaced the Web App File with the HTML File and this seems to have done the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @scros6y please add the information from your various comments to your question - comments are deleted eventually. remember: this question will hopefully help someone else in the future.